# Pressing a UITableViewCell when a cell is currently swiped open

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `MGSwipeTableCell` in my app. When a cell is swiped open to reveal buttons if I tap on another cell it dismisses the swipe cell (hides the buttons again). I want the previously swiped cell to dismiss the buttons and then select the new cell in one tap instead of two (i.e. tap off and then tap new cell). Is there any way to to do this?

Comment: I suggest you would better get answer of this from [here](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/issues/new)

Answer (score 1):

See the description below, I think this delegate function of `MGSwipeTableCell` might help you.

```
-(void) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell didChangeSwipeState:(MGSwipeState) state gestureIsActive:(BOOL) gestureIsActive
{
/**
 * Called when the user clicks a swipe button or when a expandable button is automatically triggered
 * @return YES to autohide the current swipe buttons
 **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On MGSwipeTableCell version 1.5.4 or later

`cell.touchOnDismissSwipe = YES;`

It will dismiss the cell you did swiped and also select the cell you tap